# update date for a Dataframe and join with Kafka stream data live in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-flink, spark-streaming

I have a Kafka Stream source and a map table, which I want to join and then write the data to another Kafka topic. this job runs 24/7 without stop.

My issue is that the Map table that I wish to join is partitioned on date and every day I need the new updated Map table for the join.

But when the code runs it keeps using the same old map table, day after day without updating it.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

object joiningDF{

def newDate: String = {
val dFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
dateFormat.format(System.currentTimeMillis)
 }    

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
var date=newDate
val source =spark.readStream.
      format("kafka").
      option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "....").
      option("subscribe", "....").
      option("startingOffsets", "latest").
      load()

// MAP TABLE date variable is used to get new date daily
var map=spark.read.parquet("path/day="+date)

val joinDF=source.join(map,Seq("id"),"left")

val outQ = joinDF.
  writeStream.
  outputMode("append").
  format("kafka").
  option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "...").
  option("topic", "...").
  option("checkpointLocation", "...").
  trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("300 seconds")).
  start()

  outQ.awaitTermination()
}
}
```

Is there a way to resolve it or a work around?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a FileSystem source in continuous processing mode that is watching a directory into which you atomically move new versions of the file when they are ready. This will give you an updating stream to join with.

Comment: Currently I am doing this only, I am writing updated data into a path daily and using the new path for the joins. I was wondering if we had a better solution as this felt like a roundabout way of doing it.